# Print name of the file in front of every line of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I have a lot of text files and I want to make a bash script in linux to print the name of file in each lines of file. For example I have file lenovo.txt and I want that every line in the file to start with lenovo.txt.

I try to make a "for" for this but didn't work.

```
for i in *.txt
do
        awk '{print '$i' $0}' /var/SambaShare/$i > /var/SambaShare/new_$i
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you need to pass `$i` to awk with the `-v` option. But you can also use the `FILENAME` built-in variable in awk :

```
ls *txt
file.txt    file2.txt

cat *txt
A
B
C
A2
B2
C2

for i in *txt; do 
awk '{print FILENAME,$0}' $i; 
done
file.txt A
file.txt B
file.txt C
file2.txt A2
file2.txt B2
file2.txt C2
```

An to redirect into a new file :

```
for i in *txt; do 
awk '{print FILENAME,$0}' $i > ${i%.txt}_new.txt; 
done
```

As for your corrected version :

```
for i in *.txt
do
        awk -v i=$i '{print i,$0}' $i > new_$i
done
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Using grep you can make use of the `--with-filename` (alias `-H`) option and use an empty pattern that always matches:

```
for i in *.txt
do
    grep -H "" $i > new_$i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk and Bash don't share the same variables as they are different languages with separate interpreters.  You should pass Bash variables to Awk with the `-v` option.

You should also quote your file name variables to ensure they don't get expanded as separate arguments if they contain whitespace.

```
for i in *.txt
do
    awk -v i="$i" '{print i,$0}' "$i" > "$i"
done
```

Comment: How? What is happening/not happening? What errors are you getting if any?  I tested it using example files and it works for me.